# How to wait until a copy action has finished in Yeoman

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

I'm writing a Yeoman generator and I want to copy a directory. You can find the code below. It is working properly, however, after the copying is done I want to perform further actions like an 'npm install'.
Since the copying is done asynchronously the 'npm install' is performed before all files have been copied. How can I wait until all copy actions have finished?

```
this.expandFiles('**', {
    cwd: this.sourceRoot(),
    dot: true
}).forEach(function (el) {

    this.copy(el, el);

}, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Call chain `this.copy` with `.on` and run your function on the `'end'` event.

```
this.copy(el, el)
  .on('end', function() {
     console.log("Copy is complete");
   });
```

Comment: As explanation: the end-event seems only to be called at the very end, when all generator methods have been executed.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to do it is to use a module that you can control the flow of the loop such as async so that you know when it's done.  Here is the code:

```
var me = this;
var async = require('async');

var array = this.expandFiles('**', {
    cwd: this.sourceRoot(),
    dot: true
});

async.each(array, function(el, callback) {
    me.copy(...);  // assuming that this copy() is synchronous
    callback(null);
}, function(err) {
    console.log("done with copying....");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Yeoman's this.async()

First, get the function you need to resume the generator:

```
var done = this.async();
```

After you are done copying (probably on some callback) call `done()` when you want to resume your generator.

Docs: https://yeoman.github.io/generator/RunContext.html